# How to filter using Tags for RDS DB Snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli, jmespath

I want to filter Automated RDS DB Snapshots based on tags using AWS CLI. Since AWS does not support  directly to filter tags, I tried below cli commands but I get stuck while filtering it.

Below cli is to get the snapshots which are 30 days older

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --snapshot-type automated --region us-east-1 --query 'DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime>=`2022-06-07`]'.DBSnapshotArn --output text
```

From the output of the above command, I need to verify if the required tag is present of not

```
aws rds list-tags-for-resource --resource-name arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:******:snapshot:rds:********* --query 'TagList[?PROD=`YES`] --output text
```

But I am not sure whether this is the right way to do so. Please help me on this

Comment: Well, we also don't know if "this is the right way to do so". What exactly is happening if you run your commands? Any errors?

Comment: No errors just getting empty list ```[]```

Answer (score 0):

The `TagList` array is a couple consisting of a `Key` and a `Value`, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/list-tags-for-resource.html#examples

So your query should be:

```
TagList[?Key==`PROD` && Value==`YES`]
```

For this task, you could even return a boolean, right away:

```
length(TagList[?Key==`PROD` && Value==`YES`]) != `0`
```